# Jira API POST returning (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, rest, jira

I just can't seem to figure out why I am getting a 405 "Method Not Allowed" error message..

I would like to create a new issue in my project, the key is "BS".  I copied/pasted this directly from Jira documentation and still can't get it to work.

I have tried so many different types of string variances, but this one should work.  Is it something else that might be giving me this error?

Here is my code:

```
        string stringData = @"{""fields"": {""project"":{""key"": ""BS""},""summary"": ""REST ye merry gentlemen."",""issuetype"": {""name"": ""Ticket""}}}";


            string url = @"http://HOST.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue";

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData); // or UTF8

            WebRequest wrUrl = WebRequest.Create(url);
            wrUrl.ContentType = "application/json";
            wrUrl.Method = "POST";
            wrUrl.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert
                .ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username+":"+Password));
            wrUrl.ContentLength = data.Length;

            var newStream = wrUrl.GetRequestStream();

            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(wrUrl.GetResponse().ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please point us to the JIRA documentation.

Comment: Just make sure you are calling the right endpoint i.e. the right page/class and method. e.g. If we have in the server a page/class called "Calculations", which has a couple of methods including "Add", "Subtract", "Divide", e.t.c., and you wanted to make a call to the "Add" method, you would make a call to the endpoint "domain:/Calculations/Add" including the numbers to add in the Data json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hit this exact error: a status code 405 "Method Not Allowed". It turns out the answer is literally just using HTTPS instead of HTTP. The accepted answer lacks this detail.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-issue-post

1 - try HTTPS

2 - Do you have WRITE scope?

3 - What content comes back with the response? [Could be something](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#error-responses)

4 - "You must provide a parent field with the ID or key of the parent issue."

Answer (score 0):

So to anyone having a similar problem, I'd like to leave this answer to show how I fixed it.

First off, I scrapped this whole project and used RestSharp to connect instead.  I used Postman to test my json until I got it right.  Postman has an option to convert your JSON to a C# request,  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

public class Program
{
    //This gets meta tags for the SS project and issue type "Ticket"
    // https://HOST.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=SS&issuetypeNames=Ticket&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields

    public static string url = "https://HOST.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue";
    public static string username = "YOURUSERNAME";
    public static string password = "YOURAPIKEY";



    //host:port/context/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fieldPriority = "Low";
        var fieldSubject = "Payment Problem";
        var fieldTechResource = "BLAH";
        NewJiraIssue(fieldSubject,fieldPriority, fieldTechResource);





    }

    //*****************************************
    //        Create a new Jira Issue
    //*****************************************
    //INPUT:             OUT: New Ticket Number
    //*****************************************
    static void NewJiraIssue(string fieldSubject, string fieldPriority, string fieldTechResource)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://HOST.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "ad6dbffb-89fe-4b21-b59a-0dc60724510f");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic 
KEY FROM ");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
//Created Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
//Date CR Is approved internal                                   //Customer Approval 
Sent Date                                        //Customer Approval Date:                                           
//Planned UAT Completion Date:                                      //Actual Delivery 
Date to UAT:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\r\n    \"fields\": {\r\n       
\"project\":\r\n       {\r\n          \"key\": \"SS\",\r\n           \"id\": 
\"10040\"\r\n       },\r\n       \"summary\": \""+fieldSubject+"\",\r\n       \r\n       
\"issuetype\": {\r\n          \"name\": \"Ticket\"\r\n       },\r\n       
\"customfield_10042\" : \"2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       
\"customfield_10043\" : \"customfield_10043\",\r\n\r\n       \"customfield_10067\" :  
\"customfield_10067\",\r\n       \"customfield_10068\" : 
\"customfield_10068\",\r\n\r\n       \"customfield_10070\" : \"2001-03- 
01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       \"customfield_10071\" : \"2002-03- 
01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       \"customfield_10072\" : \"2003-03- 
01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       \"customfield_10073\" : \"2004-03- 
01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       \"customfield_10074\" : \"2005-03- 
01T00:00:00.000+0400\",\r\n       \r\n       \"priority\": {\"name\": \"" + 
 fieldPriority + "\"},\r\n       \"customfield_10069\":  {\"name\" : \"" + 
fieldTechResource + "\"}\r\n}\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The difference is you were using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Once you scrapped and regenerated, your answer shows HTTPS. I just made the same mistake